# PostgreSQL encoding problem with greek characters

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I have made a database with utf8 encoding and some greek characters are not recognized in the values that I insert. I use this to create the database:

```
CREATE DATABASE greek WITH ENCODING 'UTF-8' LC_COLLATE='el_GR.utf8' LC_CTYPE='el_GR.utf8' TEMPLATE=template0;
```

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    category VARCHAR(50),
    subcategory  VARCHAR(50),
    photo VARCHAR(100),
    UNIQUE (name)
);
```

And then with this insert I try to put in the datbase these values here is how it looks in the windows [insert command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVSRV.png) command prompt:

```
INSERT INTO products VALUES
    (0,'Κύκνος Τομάτες Αποφλ Ολoκλ 400γρ','ee0022e7b1b34eb2b834ea334cda52e7','a02951b1c083449b9e7fab2fabd67198'),
    (1,'Elite Φρυγανιές Ολικής Άλεσης 180γρ','ee0022e7b1b34eb2b834ea334cda52e7','a483dd538ecd4ce0bdbba36e99ab5eb1'),
    (2,'Trata Σαρδέλα Λαδιού 100γρ','ee0022e7b1b34eb2b834ea334cda52e7','df10062ca2a04789bd43d18217008b5f'),
    (3,'Μεβγάλ Τυρί Ημισκλ Μακεδ 420γρ','ee0022e7b1b34eb2b834ea334cda52e7','4c73d0eccd1e4dde8bb882e436a64ebb');
```

when I do the select query to see the values

```
select * from products;
```

What I get is these unrecognized characters:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWNRt.png)

What should I try so that all the characters are recognized inside the database?

I tried changing the encoding of the database to WIN1252 but it did not work.

Comment: "I use the Windows command prompt to insert the values" -> can you [edit] the question to show how you do this?

Comment: In almost all cases this is caused by the application _sending_ the values. Typically because it sends the values as e.g. ISO encoded. If all tiers are correctly using UTF-8, then this won't happen: https://dbfiddle.uk/A7uwp620  If you have the INSERT in a SQL script, make sure the script is saved as UTF-8. If this is on the windows command line, make sure you change the codepage to 65001 and make sure you change psql's encoding to UTF-8 as well before "running" the script (e.g. using the `\i` directive)